# Angular sign in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I wanted to know how people would go about having a sign in page for an Angular app that was completely separate from the app and once authenticated would be passed through into the main angular app. So something like a Signin.html page that once authenticated passed onto index.html.

The thing I can't get my head around is having the moules loaded into the main app on signin.html and how you then handle moving to index.html that has its own modules and whether you can pass user information between the modules on signin -> index.html.

The way my app currently works is a modal for sign in that is part of the main ng-app and simply has the app behind it.

Comment: You should probably have a look at angular's routing capabilities, and how to build single-page apps with that. Also, interceptors for your authentication.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you may want to explore is, provided both pages are from the same origin (ex www.myapp.com/app) you may be able to store authenticated user information in local storage. Upon succesfull authentication, your signup page will save the user information in local storage using **`$localStorage`** and will direct the call to index.html. Your index will not have access to whatever stored by signup.html via local storage.

Comment: We are using indexeddb so perhaps I will store it there and retrieve the information from that.